# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ' '

Tags: python

I have Mac-address in a file.
xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx
.
.

What I'm trying to do is get 1 byte of MAC address and convert them to integer.

```
import string
with open("sample.txt", "r") as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        sample_str = line.strip()
        string1=sample_str[0:2]
        a=int(string1,16)
        print(a)
```

Also i tried with slice() but still gives me same error.

```
        string1=slice(0,2)
        print(sample_str[string1])
        #string2=str(sample_str[string1]) tried with and without this directly giving "sample_str[string1]" in int()
        print(all(c in string.hexdigits for c in sample_str[string1]))
        a=int(string2,16)
```

Question is when i try to use slice or substring , i see the string were i copied it to (by printing the string value)but when i pass this string to int with base16 ,it gives me this error
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ' '
saying there is no string which passed since there is empty " " string

However when i give string directly as say
string1="ae" (same as the one in file) everything works fine without any errors

I have very minimal experience in python, i did checkout that hex values with "0x" needs to passed as base 0 and without "0x" as prefix needs to have base16.

Any help on why such behavior is seen when i am passing the string after using substring or slice is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have empty lines in the file?

Comment: yes, there is one empty line in file

Comment: just print and see the `string1`

Comment: @bbcbbc1 You must skip that empty line then. ``if not sample_str: continue`` should work.

Comment: thank you @MisterMiyagi it worked without any errors after removing an empty line.
Thanks for the help!